# Extracting data from a facebook page using HttpRequest and HttpResponse

Tags: vb.net, facebook, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I am trying to extract some business data from Facebook pages using VB.NET. However, I am not getting the response I would expect.

```
Dim request As HttpWebRequest
Dim response As HttpWebResponse
Dim responseText As String

request = CType(WebRequest.Create(http://www.facebook.com/Microsoft))
request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)"
request.AllowAutoRedirect = True

response = CType(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
```

If I look at the text for the response I get this:

```
<html><head><title>Redirecting...</title><script>__DEV__=0;_script_path = "XVanityURLController";var uri_re=/^(?:(?:[^:\/?#]+):)?(?:\/\/(?:[^\/?#]*))?([^?#]*)(?:\?([^#]*))?(?:#(.*))?/,target_domain='';window.location.href.replace(uri_re,function(a,b,c,d){var e,f,g;e=f=b+(c?'?'+c:'');if(d){d=d.replace(/^(!|%21)/,'');g=d.charAt(0);if(g=='/'||g=='\\')e=d.replace(/^[\\\/]+/,'/');}if(e!=f)window.location.replace(target_domain+e);});</script><script type="text/javascript">/*<![CDATA[*/(function(){function si_cj(m){setTimeout(function(){new Image().src="https:\/\/error.facebook.com\/common\/scribe_endpoint.php?c=si_clickjacking&t=956"+"&m="+m;},5000);}if(top!=self && !false){try{if(parent!=top){throw 1;}var si_cj_d=["apps.facebook.com","apps.beta.facebook.com"];var href=top.location.href.toLowerCase();for(var i=0;i<si_cj_d.length;i++){if (href.indexOf(si_cj_d[i])>=0){throw 1;}}si_cj("3 ");}catch(e){si_cj("1 \t");window.document.write("\u003Cstyle>body * {display:none !important;}\u003C\/style>\u003Ca href=\"#\" onclick=\"top.location.href=window.location.href\" style=\"display:block !important;padding:10px\">Go to Facebook.com\u003C\/a>");/*kSxhSBR_*/}}}())/*]]>*/</script><script>window.location.replace("https:\/\/m.facebook.com\/AMD");</script><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=https://m.facebook.com/AMD" /></head><body></body></html>
```

However, when I use a WebBrowser it actually redirects me to the Microsoft page. I don't want to use a form though to accomplish this.

So, I'm not sure how to bypass this redirect with HttpWebRequest. Do I need to somehow login to facebook in order to get the response I'm looking for? If so, how do I do this? Please help, I've been banging my head on this for days.

---

##

Comment: You really should use the proper API.  Scraping the page, particularly a Facebook page, is unreliable.

Comment: ... and also against their ToS.

Answer (score 1):

The page is using javascript to perform the redirect.

Your HttpResponse is getting the HTML returned as string but it does not execute the JavaScript inside of it.

Try looking into using a headless web browser, such as Selenium.